# VBA : Modify & Save to .dat format without changing it to .txt format?

Tags: vba, excel, unicode

I am trying to modify and save a file.dat throught VBA. But each time the dat is saved, i have an error in a calcul servor that inform that the .dat "MAY BE A UNICODE OR OTHER BINARY FORMAT FILE ".

Is there a way to save in VBA without making the file an unicode format ?

Thank you.

Comment: Hallo @mitsuki, you should supply more data - code so we can help,

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to save your file as a .dat file, or as an .xls(x) file?

Comment: @Luuklag  i want to save it as .dat file without opening it as a text file . Once the VBA open the .dat it change it to unicode text. Is there another way to modify the file without opening it to text ?

Comment: @mitsuki What is in the file that couldn't be transformed to unicode? I doubt there is a way to not transform it, as it needs to be a file that excel can open for VBA to work.

Comment: The .dat file shouldn't be transformed to unicode . It should stay the same as it is. But when i run the macro to edit it it turn it to unicode by default. And i want to conserve the same format @Luuklag

Comment: Please share the VBA code which opens and edits the file, and some sample part of the file.